# How do I bypass pkgadd signature verification?

Tags: svn, installation, solaris

Trying to install CollabNet Subversion Client on Solaris x64, but I'm hung up with:

```
## Verifying signature for signer <Alexander Thomas(AT)>
pkgadd: ERROR: Signature verification failed while verifying certificate <subject=Alexander Thomas(AT), issuer=Alexander Thomas(AT)>:<self signed
certificate>.
```

Any way to just bypass the certificate check?  None of the options listed in the man page seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting 'authentication=nocheck' in your admin file (*/var/sadm/install/admin/default* by default).

If this doesn't work, there does not appear to be a documented way to force a package installation without a trusted CA in the keystore.

Comment: authentication=nocheck should work, see http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/817-0716/6mggehbp3?a=view

Comment: confirmed to work on Sparc 64-bit Solaris

Answer (score 5):

Download the cert next to the download link, then run pkgadm addcert -ty certificate.pem it'll work, it's in the FAQ. Caught me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Something else to keep in mind when installing CollabNet Subversion on Solaris: sudo is not installed by default. To make the installer work on my system, I had to hack the "bin/csvn" script as follows (replace sudo with 'su - root -c '<cmd>'

```
installdaemon() {
if [ `id | sed 's/^uid=//;s/(.*$//'` = "0" ] ; then
    echo "Cannot be root to perform this action."
    exit 1
else
    if [ "$DIST_OS" = "solaris" ] ; then
        echo "Detected Solaris:"
        if [ -f /etc/init.d/$APP_NAME ] ; then
            echo " The $APP_LONG_NAME daemon is already installed."
            exit 1
        else
            echo " Installing the $APP_LONG_NAME daemon.."
            # NOTE THE FOLLOWING SUBSTITUTION OF 'sudo' with 'su - root -c "<cmd>"'
            su - root -c "ln -s $REALPATH /etc/init.d/$APP_NAME"
            su - root -c "ln -s /etc/init.d/$APP_NAME /etc/rc3.d/K20$APP_NAME"
            su - root -c "ln -s /etc/init.d/$APP_NAME /etc/rc3.d/S20$APP_NAME"
        fi
```